# Zip dictionary and some constants into list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like

```
d = {1:2, 3:4}
```

and some constants `a = "foo" & b = "bar"`
I want to create a list of tuples like

```
[(1,2, "foo", "bar"), (3, 4, "foo", "bar")]
```

Is there like a zip/pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate tuples with the + operator, just like with lists:

```
>>> [i + ("foo", "bar") for i in d.items()]
[(1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'), (3, 4, 'foo', 'bar')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried any of the following list comprehensions?

```
[(k, v, a, b) for k, v in d.items()]
# [(1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'), (3, 4, 'foo', 'bar')]
```

Or,

```
[(*item, a, b) for item in d.items()]
# [(1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'), (3, 4, 'foo', 'bar')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lambda` and `map` to achieve this:

```
list(map(lambda x: tuple(list(x)+["foo", "bar"]), list(d.items())))
```

Alternatively, using

```
list(map(lambda x: x+("foo", "bar"), d.items()))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'), (3, 4, 'foo', 'bar')]
```